# How to replace ASCII code (alt+207) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which contains `square boxes`(I found it's ascii code as `alt+207`)...

How can I replace this with ' '(a single space).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you mean the character: ¤

If so, you could try,

```
str = str.replace('\u00A4', ' ');
```

Or if you want to do it to any character that is not ASCII, you could try something like:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\u000A\u0020-\u007E]/g, ' ');
```

Comment: when i tried this ` str.replace(/[^\u000A\u0020-\x007E]+/, ' '); ` browser giving me error `Invalid range in character set`

Comment: Whoops I think I put a \x where I meant \u - try again

Comment: I keep forgetting that /g in javascript.  Try now

Answer (score 0):

Is it one of these characters? `&#9642;` = ▪ or `&#9632;` = ■

If so, you can do this

```
var str ="Something &#9642; and &#9632;";
str = str.replace(/&#9642;|&#9632;/g, "&nbsp;");
document.write(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8mCuV/